Как настроить URL Rewrite Module IIS?
Есть ли у кого опыт работы с утилитой URL Rewrite Module веб-сервера IIS?
Как правильно настроить правило, чтобы следующий URL сайта всегда преобразовывался так:

C https://site.ru/name/file.exe?id=132 менялся на https://site.ru/name/filename.dll?id=132

или C https://site.ru/name/file.exe?id=132&objaction=browse менялся на


https://site.ru/name/filename.dll?id=132&objaction=browse и т.д.
У меня работает только так:

C https://site.ru/name/file.exe меняется на https://site.ru/name/filename.dll

вот web.config:
   <rewrite>
    <rules>
    <rule name="file.exe to filename.dll" patternSyntax="ExactMatch" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="file.exe" />
        <action type="Rewrite" url="filename.dll" />
    </rule>
    </rules>
   </rewrite>

По сути нужно, чтоб менялся только файл с file.exe на filename.dll, а то что перед и после имени файла с расширением в URL (любые символы, буквы, числа) сохранялось.
